# GraphQL object types members of multiple union types?

Tags: graphql

In GraphQL can an object type belong to multiple union types?

```
type Foo {
    id: String!
}
type Bar {
    number: Int!
}
union UnionA = Foo | Bar
union UnionB = Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an object type can belong to any number of union types. There's nothing in [the spec](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Unions) that explicitly prohibits that.